# Moving Borderless Forms

Tags: c#, move, borderless

I need your help with some code I found on the web a long time ago. Sadly I don't remember from where it is :( To move the borderless forms in my project I use this code snipped:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnMouseDown(e);
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
          {
               this.Capture = false;
               Message msg = Message.Create(this.Handle, 0XA1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
               this.WndProc(ref msg);
          }
}
```

My problem is that I don't completely understand how the code works. As far as I understand the event gets activated when a mouse button is clicked on the forms. Then follows the query, if the mouse click is a left click. And from there I don't know what the following code does :(

Answer (score 2):

The this.Capture=false tells the OS to stop capturing mouse events.  The Message.Create creates a new message to be send to the message loop of the current application.  0xA1 is WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN; which is a non-client left-button down message.  Meaning it simulated clicking the left mouse button on the missing border.

Windows then picks up the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level, you are sending a message to your window and having it handle it.

You are giving it a 0xA1 (WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) and by sending a 0x02 as the parameter (HTCAPTION) you fool the process into thinking you are on the caption bar. Drags on a caption bar move the window around, hence you can drag the window by using your code.

Samples of doing this at:

[C#: How to drag a from by the form and it's controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607841/c-how-to-drag-a-from-by-the-form-and-its-controls)

http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32-tips-tricks

Answer (score 0):

You're basically posting a message to the window.  A little MSDN research uncovers that the message you're posting is [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Basically, you're telling the underlying window that the left mouse button is being held down and it needs to respond to that.  That response typically happens to be dragging the window about.