# Set SizeAll cursor while moving control by handling NC_HITTEST

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, wndproc

I wrote the `WndProc` method for a moveable control such this:

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;


        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
        {

            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if ((int)m.Result == 0x1)
                m.Result = (IntPtr)0x2;

            return;
        }

            base.WndProc(ref m);


    }
```

and setted `SizeAll` cursor for the cursor property. but when we set m.Result as i did, the cursor will be `Default` in any case. How can i do?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: See [C#: How to drag a from by the form and it's controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1612156/719186)

Comment: @roryap : i mean with this way , the cursor of control will be 'Default' in any case

Comment: @hosseinsafavi -- I'm sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: @LarsTech thank you my friend. it working :)

Comment: You should handle `WM_SETCURSOR` too. 
Also you should hanlde `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` to prevent your control from being maximized when you double click on it:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle `WM_SETCURSOR` too.

Also you may want to hanlde `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` to prevent your control from being maximized when you double click on it:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;
    const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;
    const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
        return;
    }
    if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
    {
        if ((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff) == HTCAPTION)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.SizeAll;
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            return;
        }
    }
    if ((m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK))
    {
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```